# How do I achieve this smooth scroll effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so this issue has been driving me absolutely insane for a few days now and I can not seem to find an answer. I want to achieve this scroll effect [Here](https://www.intechnic.com/). However, I am also wondering if my scroll speed is only choppy on local.

First I'm thinking it may be my scroll speed on my mouse settings so I have been playing around with them, however when I scroll on my web pages I am developing locally the scrolling is choppy. Firefox is decent but still a little choppy. My laptop with just using the touch pad is a much smoother scroll.

I notice whenever I am on any other site whether it's using Firefox, Chrome, etc. the sites have a nice smooth scroll, not choppy and it almost seems as if the scroll transitions nicely and is somewhat delayed. My mouse is instant locally. I know I am all over the place here, but does anyone have an idea of what this issue may be? Is the scroll speed different locally vs hosted?

I want to achieve the page scrolling smoothly throughout, not just 100vh and using a full page scroll plugin.

Comment: you can try mcustomscrollbar jquery plugin

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin called onepage.js

Comment: Made the edit, forgot to specify, I need this smooth scroll throughout the whole site. Not for anchor tags inside the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```css
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp#section1

Comment: Appreciate the response, but I do have this implemented but this is only for jumping to anchor tags. I need something that is smooth throughout the page.